# How to interact with window behind gnome-terminal on shortcut key press?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, cursor

I often use Terminal to write code in `vim`, and as my Terminal is see-through I am able to see what it behind it, so if I have a manual behind it in a browser window or something like that, then I can refer to it without needing to switch to it or having to have it next to my Terminal window which I prefer not to do as both windows get rather small then.

But there is one downside, I often need to copy and paste text, move down the page behind Terminal, search for things on it, etc. 
And to do this, I then have to switch to it which I don't like doing, so what would be better would be if there was a way of making it so that in `gnome-terminal`, when I press a certain keyboard shortcut, for it to make my cursor go through the current window (which is see-through and should remain ontop) so that I may be able to interactive with the window behind (for instance to copy and paste text, to move down the page, and to search for things on the page) `gnome-terminal` without actually moving to it or putting it infront of the `gnome-terminal` window.

Of course pressing they keyboard shortcut again - or maybe a different one if this can't be done with the same shortcut - should return things back to normal and how they were before I first pressed the shortcut which made me interact with the window behind.

I would also like for my keyboard to interact with the window behind and not just my cursor. And I would also like for this to only  be the case for the `gnome-terminal` application as I don't want this to happen with any other applications.

*Can this be done?*

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: I just alt+tab to go to and from the windows. It's pretty speedy. If they're not set up just right then I alt+tab to the specific window wanted and then alt+tab back and then, after that, the alt+tab takes me directly to the last window opened. I don't think I had to change anything from default to configure that action.

Comment: @KGIII: Ah, but then I have to look away from my code, then I forget what it is and keep on having to go back and forwards (I get a short memory when coding for too long sometimes)... :P

Comment: I need to be able to have them both filling the whole screen, and to look at them both at the same time when interacting with them.

Comment: We do have tools to get what is the *active window*, but not the z-order of the windows, unless... you run a small background script to recorde the history of frontmost window, thus concluding the z-order. Then you can run a script to switch (toggle) between the terminal and the window directly behind it. would you consider that usefull?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Yes, though I wouldn't mind even telling it what window is behind it.

Comment: After finishing the setup: ***Aaarghh***, I missed the section in the comments that you need to look at both the code and the text behind it *at the same time* while editing/copying... Toggling between the frontmost window and the one below *if* one of the first two in z-order is a terminal window is no problem, but *editing* a window that is not the frontmost seems impossible to me. Post it nevertheless? Seems not what you are looking for...

Comment: Personally, I do a similar thing by setting my DE to "focus follows mouse" and disabling "click to raise". That way, you simply need to move the mouse on to the other window and it will immediately have focus without being raised to cover the current window. This lets me read from one window and type on another, for example. Not quite what you want but it might work as a workaround.

Comment: Ok, well why don't both of you post what you have come up with and I'll see if they will do. But is there no way of making it so that the `gnome-terminal` window is just like a partly see-through image on top (because it doesn't have to really be on top, it just needs to appear to be so)? Because I know that there is a way of making it so that you have an image which is on top of everything else and is clicked through.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: ^^

Comment: @terdon: ^^^^^^

Comment: I will, afetr teaching :0

Comment: Teaching is done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not literally what you asked for, but if you have a key combination that would automatically recognize both the `gnome-terminal` -window and the window directly below it, you could switch (toggle) between the two quickly without further effort.

The setup does exactly that: *If* (and only if) either the active window or the window directly below it is a `gnome-terminal` window, the script makes them switch places, as shown in the images. I left a few irrelevant windows to illustrate they don't take part in the toggle:

1. Having a `gnome-terminal` window on top of a `gedit` window:

   [image]
2. Pressing the shortcut:

   [image]
3. Press it again:

   [image]

And so on. As mentioned, this will only happen if *either one of the topmost windows* belongs to `gnome-terminal`.

#### How to set up

1. The script(s) need `wmctrl`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Save *both* scripts below **in one and the same directory**, since one of the scripts imports functions from the other:

   ***Script 1***
   to be saved as (exactly) `z_list.py`:
   This is actually a background script, keeping track of the z-order of windows. The z-order cannot be determined by the "normal" tools like `wmctrl` or `xdotool`. Running a simple script to keep track of the currently active window, will give us the z-order however.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import time
   import os

   rootdata = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.focus_history"

   def current_windows():
       try:
           return subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8")
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   def convert_format(w_id):
       return w_id[:2]+(10-len(w_id))*"0"+w_id[2:]

   def read_data():
       return open(rootdata).read().splitlines()

   def get_top(wlist):
       try:
           top = convert_format([l.split("#")[-1].strip() for l in \
              subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-root"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines() \
                  if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" in l][0])       
           return [l for l in wlist if top in l][0]
       except IndexError:
           pass

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       open(rootdata, "wt").write("This is an empty line")
       while True:
           time.sleep(0.5)
           wdata = current_windows()
           if wdata != None:
               wlist = wdata.splitlines()
               # get frontmost window (as in wmctrl -lG)
               top = get_top(wlist)
               oldlist = read_data()
               if not any([top == oldlist[0], top == None]):
                   # clean up closed windows
                   [oldlist.remove(l) for l in oldlist if not l.split()[0] in wdata]
                   # remove possible other mentions of the active window
                   [oldlist.remove(l) for l in oldlist if l.startswith(top.split()[0])]
                   open(rootdata, "wt").write(("\n").join([top]+oldlist))
   ```

   ***Script 2***
   to be saved as `toggle_terminal.py`:
   As mentioned, save this script in one and the same directory, together  with `z_list.py`.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import z_list

   try:
       termpid = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "gnome-terminal"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
       wlist = z_list.read_data(); top = wlist[0]; second = wlist[1]
       if any([termpid in top, termpid in second]):
           subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ia", second.split()[0]])
   except subprocess.calledProcessError:
       pass
   ```

#### How to use

Since the background script keeps track of *active windows* and creates the z-order that way, it needs to run *before* you open (at least) the windows you'd like to toggle, preferably as a Startup Application.

***To test:***

Open a terminal window, run the background script by the command:

```bsh
python3 /path/to/z_list.py
```

Open a new terminal window and (e.g.) a `gedit` window. Focus the `gedit` window and open a new terminal window on top of it. Then run in the terminal window the command:

```bsh
python3 /path/to/toggle_terminal.py
```

The windows should change places (order). Unfortunately you won't be able to run the command again (in the terminal) to bring the terminal window to top again, since the `gedit` window is now active :). You may assume however it will work from a shortcut key.

***If all works fine, make the setup permanent:***

- Add `z_list.py` to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/z_list.py"
  ```
- Add script 2 to a shortcut key combination: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/toggle_terminal.py
  ```

Comment: Jacob: [FYI](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25640114#25640114)

Comment: It's called a "Spelingsfaut" ;-)